# How can I avoid android studio having an out of sync build?

Tags: android, android-studio

Occasionally the code I'm debugging in Android Studio it will not be in sync with what's running on the emulator, and I have to click "Refresh all gradle projects".

Is there a way of avoiding this? I only edit code through android studio so I don't understand why this keeps happening.

Comment: *code will not be in sync* Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Did you mean sync when build.gradle change? maybe related with your computer time.